Is a question on corporate finance ok in the Quantitive Finance forum?
I would like to post a question on the basic principle of Assets=Liabilities + Equity, and how to finance sales growth.
Is this ok on this forum?

i think stuff such as pecking order theory and other academic research in the field should b allowed. If its company specific maybe not. 

I agree: Academic research on corporate finance type questions that discuss some model will probably be on-topic. I don't think OP was aiming for that here though.

Thanks for asking but I'm afraid not. Depending on the company you could try startups.
